# Ударение в фамилии Балунов

Tags: фонетика

Как правильно ставится ударение в фамилии Балунов?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

На фамилии почти нет единых орфоэпических правил, а уж для ударения каждый носитель вправе выбирать свой вариант, исходя из семейных традиций или просто по собственному вкусу.

Если же исходить из статистических закономерностей и предположить, что основой фамилии служит имя нарицательное *бал**у**н* (тот, кто бал**у**ет,  ср: *ревун, пестун, ворчун*), то ударение должно быть на последнем слоге. Это следует из того, что суффикс "ун" в основе нормативно ударный (примеры - выше), а при образовании притяжательной формы на "-ов" ударение столь же нормативно с последнего слога основы смещается на этот суффикс.

Но, повторяю, это только общие соображения, сам Балунов может иметь собственное мнение на этот счет, и его придется уважать.